How to perform redirect in HTMX based on response from the Spring boot JSON rest API?
I am checking examples of Htmx + Spring. All examples use server-side template engines ( like Thymeleaf or Jte).
Htmx expects an HTML response from Spring, but Nowadays, most Spring applications provide a Rest API with a JSON response instead.
Is there any way to redirect in HTMX based on Rest Response from Spring boot Rest API?
Basic requirement:
Login.html 
    -> on login action using hx-post="/login" 
        -> Check the response
            -> If successful, then redirect to the dashboard.html 
            -> If error, stay on the same page and show an error message.

Manage-User.html
   -> Submit new user request hx-post="/users"
        -> Check the response
            -> If successful, then go to view user page with data (using client-side template engine like moustache)
            -> If error, stay on the same page and show the error message.

I know it can be achieved by writing JavaScript, but I want to know if any other way exists.
Htmx supports hx-redirect but it will only work if the server sends in the header but there is no way to define redirect based on response code/response data.

Please [edit] your post title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is primarily the useless repetition of the tag information. Tags should not appear in the title at all in most cases. The title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].

Changed title and expectation from the question. I hope now the question is clear to understand.
